# Nested foreach in php showing only last record..!

Tags: php, join, opencart, opencart2.x

On the product page of Opencart, I want to show same brand products list by categories.
With the code below the Categories in which specific brand products are available are showing.  But products are not showing under the categories. Products are showing under one category only. Adding screenshot of the result page.

[image]

Need little help from experts for this.

My code:

model/catalog/product.php

```
    public function getManufacturerCategories($manufacturer_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT c.category_id,cd.name
    FROM
    ". DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m 
    LEFT JOIN ". DB_PREFIX. "product p ON (m.manufacturer_id = p.manufacturer_id)
    LEFT JOIN ". DB_PREFIX. "product_to_category p2c ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)
    LEFT JOIN ". DB_PREFIX. "category c ON (c.category_id = p2c.category_id)
    LEFT JOIN ". DB_PREFIX. "category_description cd ON (cd.category_id = p2c.category_id)
    WHERE
    p.status = 1
    AND m.manufacturer_id = '".(int)$manufacturer_id."'
    AND c.status= 1
    ");

    return $query->rows;

    }

    public function getProductSameBrand($manufacturer_id,$product_id,$cat_id,$cat_name) {

        $product_data = array();

        $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT 
        DISTINCT p.manufacturer_id,p.product_id,p2c.category_id,cd.name
        FROM 
        " . DB_PREFIX . "product p
         LEFT JOIN ". DB_PREFIX. "product_to_category p2c ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)
         LEFT JOIN ". DB_PREFIX. "category_description cd ON (cd.category_id = p2c.category_id)
        WHERE        
        cd.name = '".$cat_name."'
        AND p.manufacturer_id = '".(int)$manufacturer_id."'
        "
        );

            foreach ($query->rows as $result2) {

            $product_data[$result2['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result2['product_id']); 

            }    

            return $product_data;

        }
```

controller/product/product.php

```
   $data['category_brand'] = array(); 

        if((int)$product_info['manufacturer_id'] > 0){ 
        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getManufacturerCategories($product_info['manufacturer_id']);
        }

         foreach ($results as $result) { 
             $cat_name =    $result['name'];
             $cat_id = $result['category_id'];

                $data['category_brand'][] = array(               
                    'category_id' => $cat_id,
                    'name'         =>  $cat_name
                );


            $data['products_brand'] = array();


             if((int)$product_info['manufacturer_id'] > 0){ 

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductSameBrand($product_info['manufacturer_id'],$this->request->get['product_id'],$cat_id,$cat_name);

                } 

            foreach ($results as $result2) {


                $data['products_brand'][] = array(

                    'product_id' => $result2['product_id'], 
                    'name'         => $result2['name'],
                    'catname'      => $cat_name,
                    'href'         => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result2['product_id'])

                );

            }

            }
```

view/product/product.tpl

```
     <?php foreach ($category_brand as $cat) { ?>
                            <h4><?php echo $cat['name']; ?></h4>  
                          <?php foreach ($products_brand as $product) { ?>
                          <?php if($cat['name']==$product['catname']){?>
                         <a href="<?php   echo $product['href']; ?>"> <?php echo $product['name']; ?></a><br/>
                         <?php } ?>
                         <?php } ?>
                         <hr/> 
                    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved.. 
I needed to put
 $data['products_brand'] = array();

above first foreach statment